# PowerShell - Return doesn't behave as expected

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm using PowerShell v5.1.
I have a question about "Return". Shouldn't "Return" stop script execution?

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | ForEach-Object {
    "Exiting"
    Return
}
"It doesn't"

ForEach ($number in 1..2){
    "Exiting"
    Return
}
"It doesn't"
```

Result is: Exiting => It doesn't => Exiting

As you can see "Return" behaves differently inside "ForEach-Object" loop then inside "ForEach" loop. What am I missing? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the manual, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-5.1

Emphasis added:

Exits the current scope, which can be a **function, script, or script block.**

Any time you hit the Return keyword it'll exit the brackets currently be worked within.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but why does it behave differently for those two loops. Both of them are executing "Script Block ... { }" so, the expected result should be "Exiting => It doesn't => Exiting => It doesn't"

Comment: OK, NO, both of them are not executing Script Block, only ForEach-Object does. My fault. Should have read help for ForEach-Object more carefully. Thank you.

Comment: Tim, perhaps you could expand on the difference between a script block and whatever the brackets in the `ForEach` command are doing?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore yeahh, but this is not true. ForEach is an alias of ForEach-Object when piping. ForEach in example I've posted is a ForEach, not an alias. But thank you all. After reading the documentation it's clearly defined how "ForEach" is a loop while ForEach-Object is a cmdlet that executes ScriptBlock, and there is a difference. That is a reason why in "ForEach" loop "Return" exits the script and in "ForEach-Object" cmdlet "Return" exits only the ScriptBlock.